# Basis consisting of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

How to find a basis consisting of eigenvectors for the following matrix?
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1 & -1 \\-1 & 3 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$
Any tips would be great, thanks.

Comment: First, compute the eigenvalues...

Comment: Can you find it's eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Yep got the eigenvalues which were x=1 and 4 (which was repeated)  and eigenvectors from null space of (A-xI)

Comment: Does that basis have to be an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors?

Comment: @EdenHazard You should be able to check orthogonality. (Hint: If the eigenspace has dimension >1 use Gram-Schmidt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

- compute eigenvalues by $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$
- for each $\lambda$ solve $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ to determine eigenvectors $x$

Note that since the matrix is real symmetric we can find an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: I am familiar with finding orthogonal basis if it consists of 2 vectors but not three do you know what we do in this case?

Comment: the method is almost the same, youjust need to solve a system of three unkown but the concept behind are the same

Comment: Let me know for any needing in the solution

Comment: I found one ,1/root3 [1 1 1] which is the obvious one , stuck on other two

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add you work to the OP in order to cal help you. I could add details but it requires a few of time. How many and wich eigenvalues have you found?

Comment: eigenvalues 2 and 4(which has algebraic multiplicity 2)

Comment: It is not possible since the trace of the matrix is 9, maybe the first is 1? Remember indeed that the sum of e-values = trace(A).

Comment: yes 1 my mistake

Comment: Ok then you have found the eigenvectors for 1, you don't need to normalize it is simply (1,1,1).

Comment: For the e-value 4 note the the matrix become all -1 tus it reduce to the single equation x+y+z=0 and you can easily find  two solution linearly independent for example taking x=t, y=s, z=-s-t and obtain for (t,s)=(1,0) the e-vector (1,0,-1) and for (t,s)=(0,1) the other (0,1,-1) and you are done.

Comment: I thought length of vectors in orthogonal basis have to be equal to 1

Comment: You can also normalize in this case the basis is said to be $\color{red}{orthonormal}$ but to be orthogonal you don't need.

Comment: I get you now thanks a lot

Comment: Well done, You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

A first guess is that all three rows add up to $1$, so $\left[\begin{array}{r}1&1&1\end{array}\right]^{\text{T}}$ is an eigenvector. Thus, the other two eigenvertors must be orthogonal to it (i.e., their entries must add up to zero). Such guesses as $\left[\begin{array}{r}1&-1&0\end{array}\right]^{\text{T}}$ and $\left[\begin{array}{r}1&1&-2\end{array}\right]^{\text{T}}$ would do.

Comment: Sorry, My bad!!

Comment: yeah I got [-1 1 0] and [-1 0 1] using method stated below, would these also be allowed to use?

Comment: @EdenHazard for the eigenvalue $4$, you are not getting $2$ vector, but the whole span of the $2$ vector, and you can choose any vector from there.

Comment: So from $v_1=[-1,1,0]^T$ and $v_2=[-1,0,1]^T$, $-v_1$ and $v_1-2v_2$ will span the same space as $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: makes sense thanks